# Extend Interface Implementation?

Tags: c#, interface, factory-pattern

I have a small object factory that creates two types of objects. Now I want to add new method to a 2nd object but without changing interface since I must implement that method in the 1st object too. How to do it?

```
public class LookupFactory
{
    public ILookups CreateLookups()
    {
        ILookups dbLookup = null;
        var databaseType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseType"].ToString();

        switch (databaseType.ToLower())
        {
            case "oracle":
                dbLookup = new Lookups();
                break;
            case "mssql":
                dbLookup = new SqlLookups();
                break;
        }

        return dbLookup;
    }
}
```

My interface looks like this:

```
public interface ILookups
{
    List<Region> GetRegions(string language);

    List<Industry> GetIndustries(string language);

    List<Dimension> GetDimensions(string language);

    List<SubjectType> GetSubjectTypes(string language);
 }
```

I want to add method GetPeople to SqlLookups object only.

Comment: Clearly there some reason why you can't simply "add new method to a 2nd object" - would you mind clarifying what it is? (Possibly related how you plan to use the objects)

Comment: You can add that method just fine, but then you can't call it from a `ILookups` reference. You'll have to test whether the returned instance is a `SqlLookups` (or rather a `IGetPeople`), cast it to that and then call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ask yourself the question how it should work from the "consumer side".

As a starting point I'd do it this way:

1. Generate a refined interface implemented only by certain classes:

   ```
   public interface ILookups
   {
       List<Region> GetRegions(string language);
       List<Industry> GetIndustries(string language);
       List<Dimension> GetDimensions(string language);
       List<SubjectType> GetSubjectTypes(string language);

       // maybe add this
       // this makes it clear to the consumer that it could receive an extended lookup
       // one class returns "this", the other "null" 
       IExtendedLookUps GetExtendedOrNull { get;}
   }

   public interface IExtendedLookups : ILookups
   {
       List<People> GetPeople();
   }

    void consumerCode()
    {
       ILookups lookups = factory.CreateLookups();

       // code that works for both cases
       lookups.GetRegions("en");

       // do something special if it implements IExtendedLookups
       if (lookups is IExtendedLookups)
       {
           var extendedLookups = lookups as IExtendedLookups;
           extendedLookups.GetPeople();
       }
       // or with the additional interface property:
       var maybeExtendedLookups = lookups.GetExtendedOrNull;
       if (maybeExtendedLookups  != null)
       {
           maybeExtendedLookups.GetPeople();
       }

    }
   ```
2. If the extra method is relevant only for a single purpose (e.g. generating a certain report), then maybe include this report generation in the interface.
3. If there is a suitable "default" value (like an empty list in your case), add it to the other class. If there is no suitable default, don't do it.

As a summary: It all depends on how you want to use it. Design from usage to implementation not the other way round!

Comment: Use double indentation (i.e. 8 spaces) to format code inside a list.

Comment: While this works as intended it ships the `GetExtendedOrNull `-property of `ILookUp` to the extended interface as well. So when accessing any member of `IExtendedILoopkup` you have this property also as it is inherited from the base-interface.

Comment: @HimBromBeere If this is not what you want, don't let the `IExtendedILookup` inherit from `ILookup`! So you can access the "regular" methods via `ILookup` and the additional via `IExtendedLookup`.

Comment: For now it is only one new method but I want my solution to be ready for future changes.

I followed your tip but now I have error on build because my factory returns ILookups and doesn't fit to IExtendedLookups now. 

Should I fix my factory or... ?

Comment: @goran85 The `SqlLookups` has to implement both interfaces now of course!

Comment: @Onur I have like this. (Resharper says base class is redundant but i left it still)

 class SqlLookups : ILookups, IExtendedSqlLookups {..}

When I call factory method GetPeople is not recognized since object on which I try to call it is ILookups.

Comment: @goran85 That's right and expected. You need to cast to `IExtendedSqlLookups` or use the `GetExtendedOrNull` if implemented in `ILookups`.

Comment: @Onur yes, I figured that i need to cast to IExtendedSqlLookups but was not sure where exactly. I casted object returned form factory just before cosuming an object and it is fine. The only thing that seems like a problem: if I put casting inside of if statement like you did I get error : Invalid embedded statement

Comment: @Onur 3rd line

           var dbLookup = _lookupFactory.CreateLookups();
            if (dbLookup is IExtendedSqlLookups)
                var extendedLookups = dbLookup as IExtendedSqlLookups;

Comment: @goran85 Did you omit the `{}`?

Comment: Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement

Comment: @Onur, oh yes. rookie mistake. Thanks for your time and effort. I learned something out of this. To others: No.1 is the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if two classes implement one interface they must implement all methods. So, if you want to add new method to your interface, you have to implement it in both `Lookups` and `SqlLookups`.
Possible solutions:

1. Create new interface `IExtendedLookups : ILookups` and add new
   method to `IExtendedLookups` and make class `SqlLookups : IExtendedLookups`
   Your factory should return ILookups but later in code you have to check returned value:

   ```
   var lookups = factory.CreateLookups();
   var extendedLookups = lookups as IExtendedLookups;
   if (extendedLookups != null)
   {
       //...call extendedLookups.GetPeople();
   }
   ```
2. Add new method to ILookups, implement in both classes but in Lookups do it like this:

   ```
   public List<People> GetPeople()
   {
       throw new NotSupportedException();
   }
   ```

Comment: I think that throwing a `NotSupportedException` is a bad idea. If the method isn't relevant to an interface, it shouldn't be part of it.

Comment: @DavidG I agree with you, it's bad in common, but we don't know the situation. So, it may be a solution, but it's not good one

Comment: 2nd solution is what I'm trying to avoid, so i tried no.1.

I followed your tip but now I have error on build because my factory returns ILookups and doesn't fit to IExtendedLookups now. 

Should I fix my factory or... ?

Comment: @goran85 IExtendedLookups implements ILookups, so it is ok to return IExtendedLookups (or, you can always cast to ILookups)